# Array.find Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda, este problema lo pude resolver con un simple `for` pero bueno, no puedo dormir con las dudas.

Usando el `Array.find()` se supone que trabaja tomando el primer resultado encontrado de lo que se solicité, yo quería usarlo para *encontrar* una cadena de archivo que viene en dos formatos; para moverlo de un folder a otro.

```
let archivos = ['prueba1','prueba2','prueba4','prueba5'];
let carpeta = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/archivos');
archivos.forEach(function(element) {

  carpeta.find(function(param) {
    let file = param.split(".");
    console.log(file[0])
      if (file[0] === element) {
        fs.renameSync(__dirname + '/archivos/' + file[0] + '.txt', __dirname + '/movidos/' + file[0] + '.txt')
        fs.renameSync(__dirname + '/archivos/' + file[0] + '.rar', __dirname + '/movidos/' + file[0] + '.rar')
      }
  })
})
```

Algo simple como esto, pero al ejecutarlo funciona solo una vez y vuelve a preguntar por el mismo archivo y es ahí cuando ya no funciona, no entiendo por que se *encicla* dentro del find.

Si alguien sabe a fondo el comportamiento de esta función se lo agradecería :)

Answer (score 2):

La función `find` itera sobre los contenidos de una arreglo evaluando una función para cada elemento. Devolverá el primer elemento para el cual la función se evalué como "verdadera" (`truthy`) esto es, el booleano `true`, un número distinto a cero, un string no vacío, etc.

```
let numeros = [1,2,3,4,5];

function igualATres(num) {
  return num === 3;
};

let encontrado = numeros.find((num)=>{
  return igualATres(num);
});
```

Lo de arriba hace que se recorra cada elemento del array. Si en un momento del bucle se retorna algo `truthy` entonces se cortocircuita la iteración: ya se encontró un candidato, ese es el resultado de `find`.

Si en ningún momento se retorna un truthy, **la función sigue recorriendo el array completo** y cuando éste se termina dice que el resultado es `undefined`.

En tu caso, no estás usando `find` para su propósito sino que estás usando su efecto colateral como iterador genérico, tal como lo harías con un foreach, y esto es porque **no estás retornando** sino ejecutando una acción dada la condición.

Entonces se produce el flujo:

- Tengo ['archivo1.rar','archivo1.txt'] y otros en mi carpeta. Es un array de strings y no cambia acorde a cambios en los archivos luego de haber llenado el array.
- Busco archivos que empiecen con `archivo1`
- `archivo1.rar` cumple la condición
- Renombro `archivo1.rar` y `archivo1.txt` moviéndolos de carpeta
- En la iteración siguiente, `carpeta` todavía contiene `archivo1.txt`
- `archivo1.txt` cumple la condición
- Intento renombrar `archivo1.rar` y `archivo1.txt` moviéndolos de carpeta
- Como ya los moví, ocurre un error, los archivos ya no están ahí.

Un bucle que en cambio funcionaría, sería ocupar find para su humilde propósito específico. Nada de lógica, sólo devolver verdadero o falso.

```
archivos.forEach(function (element) {

    let encontrado = carpeta.find(function (param) {
        let file = param.split(".");
        return file[0] === element; // <-- corto circuito
    });
    if (encontrado) {
        console.log(`Archivo encontrado es ${encontrado}`);
        let file = encontrado.split(".");
        fs.renameSync(__dirname + '/archivos/' + file[0] + '.txt', __dirname + '/movidos/' + file[0] + '.txt');
        fs.renameSync(__dirname + '/archivos/' + file[0] + '.rar', __dirname + '/movidos/' + file[0] + '.rar');
    }
});
```

En tu carpeta hay ocho archivos. Para cada una de las cuatro condiciones hay dos archivos que la satisfacen. Gracias al corto circuito sólo obtienes la primera ocurrencia. Iteras sobre cuatro condiciones, obtienes cuatro candidatos, renombras dos archivos por cada candidato.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon!.

No lo mire desde ese punto de funcion, y si es verdad no lo use de la forma correcta es por que me da el mismo error que especificas. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme y con tanto detalle.